# Trouble with absolutely positioned "pop-up"

Tags: html, css

I am doing a popup on a clients site for their new restaurant location. The base site is kind of a cookie cutter type site, and very messy (I'm not sure if I should attribute this to the problem). Everything was going fine until I added some divs that were positioned relatively and had width and height to the absolute div "pop-up". Now, the popup pushes the base site down, and the popup goes behind (it has a z-index of 10?). Here is the brand new css:

http://addproxy.net/sites/testing_space/css/style.css

and the site is down a level:

http://addproxy.net/sites/testing_space/

And a mockup of the desired effect (disregard the backslashes, hit max of href):

//http://addproxy.net/sites/testing_space/popup-mockup.jpg

The divs that seemed to trigger the problem were the .coupon class

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed the original content inside of your new div's.

To make it look  like your image that would be the id="coupons" div. Just so we're clear it's the one that starts like this:

```
<div id="coupons">
<div class="coupon" style="background:url(images/bg1.png);">
```

You need to move that div (and all it's contents) to just after the end tag of the id="popup" div.